# Granting access to a specific pipeline in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way in which a user can be granted access to a specific pipeline in Jenkins? This would mean that the user in question would not have access to all pipelines that are part of a group, but just a select few pipelines which are in that group.

Find below an example, the following pipelines are part of a Jenkins group:

Pipeline A

Pipeline B

Pipeline C

Pipeline D

The requirement is that the user could access pipeline A, but not Pipelines B, C and D.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/releases/
or https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/

it will add global/per-folder/per-job configuration where you can add user/group and enable/disable specific permissions like view job/run job/configure job etc...

matrix - simple plugin, just go to job and click checkboxes

role plugin - has more configuration fields, possible to crate group of users and match jobs by regex